# Set a 'link' function to run after template render with angular ui-router?

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have an angular setup that needs to work with some jQuery plugin.

Learned that the best way to achieve this is by creating a directive and activating the jQuery at the "link" stage after all information has been added to the directive

```
app.directive('directiveName', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            //my jQuery
        }
    };
});
```

`<div directiveName ></div>`

However my code works with ui-router in this way:

```
app.config(function($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    $stateProvider.state('view1', {
        url: '/view1/:param/',
        templateUrl: 'view1.html',
        controller: 'View1Ctrl'
    });
});
```

`<div ui-view></div>`

**How do I set a function to run after linking?** (ie. when scope changes)

Comment: Is there any particular scope property you're wanting to watch for changes on before running your function? Or just generally after the linking function executes?

Comment: router doesn't matter... link will fire when element actually exists. If there are other issues it's not related to router

Comment: @charlie what am I missing then? I need to run a function after ui-router has rendered the html in the ui-view. So how do I do that?

Comment: @caleb I prefer to run the post compilation function after the ui-view was completely loaded. But if you have a solution that watches a specific scope property then I would love to see it!

Comment: what does this plugin do?

Answer (score 2):

OK, so based on the conversation above, there are two solutions that might help you.

**1** A simple `$scope.$watch` in your directive/controller.

```
scope.$watch('property.to.watch', function(newValue, oldValue){
  if (newValue) {
    yourFunction();
  }
});
```

**2** Performing your action on `$viewContentLoaded`

You can either perform this in your directive/controller *or* inside a run block for your entire application. I'll demonstrate the latter.

```
.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.on('$viewContentLoaded', function(event) {
    yourFunction();
  });
```

Hope that works for you. **Edit** also, take a look at the [event documentation for UI-Router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki), you might find it very helpful.

Comment: Thanks Caleb, however I tried both options and none of them did what I wanted... I would like to run a callback after the view has completely rendered but apparently `on('$viewContentLoaded')` does NOT really do that, nor does the other option. :'(

Comment: What is your plugin supposed to do then and why do you need to wait for it to compile the view?

Comment: I need to run a jquery function after compiling the view ;)